# jquery.validate: Validating input texts with dynamic names

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm currently using the jquery.validate.js plugin and I am absolutely loving it! I'm using it right now to validate existing jsp pages (which I did not make) and it's really easy to use. However, I stumbled upon a problem with validating input texts with dynamic names.

Here's the current layout of the div:

`<input type="text" name="employee[0].firstName"/>`

`<input type="text" name="employee[1].firstName"/>`

`<input type="text" name="employee[2].firstName"/>`

`<input type="text" name="employee[3].firstName"/>`

There is also an option where a user can create another employee first name textfield by clicking "Add new text field". With that, another text field will be created with the `name="employee[4].firstName"`

How do I validate field like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a selector as specific to your required `name` as possible.
You can use jQuery's [**starts with selector(^=)**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and jQuery's [**ends with selector($=)**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) together

```
$('input[name^="employee["][name$="].firstName"]').each(function(){
    // demo purpose: prints each element's name to the console log
    console.log(this.name);

    // enter your validation for each element in here.
})​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XMTun/)

Comment: Brilliant! I'm kinda confused with the usage of selectors though, I would appreciate it if you could explain how those selectors worked like the way it did.

Comment: The selector is asking for any elements which have a `name` starting with `employee[` and ending with `].firstName`, ignoring the index value in between. I also linked the documentation to the starts-with and ends-with selectors. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wild card to get all input with name like employee.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BXQBm/1/)**

```
$('input[name^=employee]').each(function(){
  alert("Validate here"+ $(this).attr('name'));
        //validate here
});
```